# Do you need special recessed LED housing for angled / sloping ceilings?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, led, recessed-lighting

Do you need special recessed LED housing for angled / sloping ceilings?
I see that they sell them, but if there are enough recessed LEDs installed for good coverage, can't I just use regular housings? At the most get inserts that pivot.

Does anyone have any good experience here?

Comment: Well, if you blanket every inch of the ceiling with 180 degree coverage surface mounted emitters, you are okay. Every other configuration depends on what the lighting spread of the individual devices are and the level and evenness of coverage you want.

Comment: One of the best features of LED light is it's easy to aim.  So you can light the floor and workspace instead of wasting it making the walls bright.  Bounce light is overrated (well to be more precise, it is inefficient.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A housing can either take a bulb or a retrofit LED ring that sits on the end.  If you use a bulb (LED or otherwise) then the angled housing can be of benefit, by keeping the beam pointed in the downward direction.  However if you're using a flat LED ring, there's no benefit to using an angled housing, because it's going to sit on the slope anyhow.

If you're concerned about lighting the area in a downward fashion, you can either use an angled housing:

[image]

with a LED bulb in it:

[image]

or use a standard housing:

[image]

with what's called a "gimbal" fixture.  A gimbal fixture looks like this:

[image]

And will allow you to compensate for the slope in the ceiling, by pivoting the fixture inside the housing.